# Does all the roots of the polynomial in this form can be some pairwise distinct integers?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Let $n\geq 3$ be an odd number and $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_{2n}$ be pairwise distinct integers. Suppose that $(X-r_1)(X-r_2)\ldots(X-r_{2n}) = X^{2n} + \sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_{i}X^{2n-i}$. Can we have $a_1 = a_3 = a_5 = \ldots = a_{n-2} = 0$?

The motivation of the question above is to know whether or not the "non trivial" solution of this diophantine equation exists:
$$r_{1}^{2k+1}+\ldots+r_{2n}^{2k+1}=0$$
for all $0\leq k\leq \frac{n-3}{2}$.

Since $r_{1}^{2k+1}+\ldots+r_{2n}^{2k+1}=0$ is equivalent to $r_{1}^{2k+1}+\ldots+r_{n}^{2k+1}=(-r_{n+1})^{2k+1}+\ldots+(-r_{2n})^{2k+1}=0$, "non trivial" solution means $r_i$ aren't all zero and $\{r_1, \dots, r_n\} \neq \{-r_{n+1}, \dots, -r_{2n}\} $ for all rearrangement of $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_{2n}$

Comment: You should write out a couple example polynomials, I think the indices $i$ for which $a_i=0$ may need to be adjusted.

Comment: I added $n\geq 3$ in the question. Is that what you mean? Some cases for n small could be easy, I only want to know in general case, that why I forgot this condition.

Comment: They can. Put all coefficients equal to zero. The polynomial is $X^{2n}$, which has all of its roots integer.

Comment: If we add the condition "all the roots of $P$ are some distinct integers", does such $P$ exists?

Comment: Where does the question come from or what motivates it? Just curiosity?

Comment: Briefly, in the elementary geometry, given a point $P$ and a conic, by choosing an arbitrary line passe through $P$, rotating this line $n-1$ times by an angle of $\pi/n$ radians, these lines intersect the conic at $2n$ points, these $2n$ points form 2n segments with the point $P$, then the polynomial of $2n$degree ,whose roots are the length of these 2n segment, has exactly the form $a_1 = a_3 = \ldots = a_{n-2} =0$.

Comment: By Newton's identity, the condition $a_1= a_3 = \ldots = a_{n-2} = 0$ impose some identities for the power sum of $r_1,\ldots,r_{2n}$, which have a taste of number theory. So I consider the question for the integer rather then the length of the segments constructed by cutting conic. Maybe some theorems about polynomial could be useful, so I posted the question in this way.

Comment: By trivial solution, what exactly do you mean. $r_1, \dots, r_{2n}=0$ ? Obviously, $-n, -(n-1), \dots, -1, 1, \dots, n-1, n$ always satisfies this equation

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=3$. Take such integers, so that $r_1+r_2+\dots+r_6=0$. For example, $-6, -2, -1, 2, 3, 4$.
Then we'll have $a_1=0$, so it's possible. Now, is it possible for every odd $n\geq 3$ ?